Unable to see Connect tab in Astra DB
While I am trying to connect the Document API with my database in DataStax AstraDB, there is no "Connect" tab appearing where I can link my database to the Document API. I am new to this; is there anything I am missing?

I believe you're referring to this tab on the Astra DB dashboard:

The Connect tab is only available on "standard" Astra databases. It is not available on vector databases (tagged with the purple "Vector" pill):

Note that the Document API is a legacy interface that has been replaced by the Data API clients on Astra Vector databases. If you are building new applications, we recommend that you use the new Data API since the older Stargate APIs have been deprecated. Cheers!

There are a couple unknowns here and I am happy to edit my response if you can add additional details in your original question.
Let's assume you're using Java client in your application to access Astra DB's Data API. There is no concept of "linking" your cluster to the document API as its enabled.
Check out the prerequisites section of this Java client documentation page which needs the following,

Astra account (which you already have, I assume). If not, do so here.
Serverless (Vector) flavor database created. I assume this is also done.
You've generated an application token that has the right access level roles (generally with Database Administrator role).
On your database’s Overview tab, copy your database’s API endpoint. The endpoint format is https://ASTRA_DB_ID-ASTRA_DB_REGION.apps.astra.datastax.com.

Having all the above, all you need is below in your code to use the Data API.
import com.datastax.astra.client.Collection;
import com.datastax.astra.client.DataAPIClient;
import com.datastax.astra.client.Database;
import com.datastax.astra.client.model.Document;
import com.datastax.astra.client.model.FindIterable;
import com.datastax.astra.client.model.SimilarityMetric;

public class Quickstart {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Loading Arguments
    String astraToken = System.getenv("ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN");
    String astraApiEndpoint = System.getenv("ASTRA_DB_API_ENDPOINT");

    // Initialize the client
    DataAPIClient client = new DataAPIClient(astraToken);
    System.out.println("Connected to AstraDB");

    Database db = client.getDatabase(astraApiEndpoint);
    System.out.println("Connected to Database.");
  }
}

Once you've connected to the cluster from your application, you can refer to the full Data API spec and details here in this documentation. Cheers!

p/s: There used to be an old & now not-so-maintained/deprecated Document API in Astra DB non-vector clusters. It is now recommended to leveraged the Data API (fka JSON API) in vector type Astra DB clusters which is more feature-rich than the older document API to deal with JSON structures.
